# Citrus plant with strong growth but yellowish/lime-green leaves

Tags: plant-health, leaves, growth, citrus

I know that (generally speaking) yellowish to lime-green leaves combined with slow/weak growth in a plant are an indication of inadequate nitrogen, and one must fertilize accordingly.

However, does the same apply for a plant that is showing considerable growth but with pale-colored leaves?

Consider this calamansi (*citrofortunella microcarpa*):

[image]

The previous growth (before I bought it) consists of small, dense, dark-green leaves. The growth since then takes the form of much larger and paler foliage.

I do fertilize (though not too much), and the leaves are from the same stem so it's not graft vs host.

Am I doing anything wrong or is everything normal?

Comment: I can't see anything with that magenta colored lighting.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I'm guessing that it was kept in a greenhouse or outdoors before you purchased it and that now you are keeping it indoors under a grow light (hence the magenta tinting of your photo).

Comment: @JimYoung that is correct. It's too cold here in Illinois for it to be out of doors just yet.

Comment: we need a picture in good light of a close up of the new growth.  The usual suspect is not nitrogen deficiency but iron/manganese deficiency brought on by alkaline water changing the soil pH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They look like a normal growth of fresh green new leaves to me.  They are often a paler green for a time until they mature over the seasons growth.  It looks very healthy to me There may be deficiencies but it's not clear to me from this picture.

Comment: Why are they so much bigger than the existing growth, though?

Comment: Possibly/maybe because the older leaves are from the  original tip cutting whose leaves would have been smaller.  With the newer leaves having the benefit of a root system and fresh soil from which to draw nutrients. It may well just be getting into its stride and growing well.  From the picture it looks as though you are doing everything right.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi it does indeed look healthy

Comment: No worries glad to be able to help